# Melhorando a Lógica do Login - JDBC - JavaWeb

Tags: java, query, jdbc, revisão-de-código

Estou desenvolvendo o método de login de uma aplicação, porém estive percebendo que a *query* que estou executando para verificar se um usuário está cadastrado no sistema e se a senha dele bate com o dado do banco é muito lenta. Eu estou usando o `Select * FROM cadastrados`, que acaba verificando todo o banco de dados deixando a aplicação mais "lenta".

Alguém pode me sugerir uma *query* melhor para o método do login ou uma lógica melhor do que a que estou usando? Abaixo, segue o código:

```
//Login Usuário
public static Usuario Login(String login, String senha){
    Connection conn = Banco.getConexao();
    Usuario user = new Usuario();
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String sql = "Select * FROM cadastrados";

    try{
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        while(rs.next()){
            //Lógica do Login
            if(rs.getString(2).equals(login) && rs.getString(3).equals(senha)){
                user.setCpf(rs.getString(1));
                user.setLogin(rs.getString(2));
                user.setSenha(rs.getString(3));
                user.setNome(rs.getString(4));
                user.setSobrenome(rs.getString(5));
                user.setEndereco(rs.getString(6));
                user.setEmail(rs.getString(7));
                user.setLogado(true);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException ex){
        Logger.getLogger(UsuarioDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    finally{
        Banco.closeConexao(conn, rs, null, stmt);
    }
    return user;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde!

Você poderia usar a cláusula `where` em sua sql, passando o usuário e a senha, deixar o db fazer a pesquisa e te entregar o usuário correto, melhorando a segurança e legibilidade do seu código, ao invés de obter todas as contas e fazer a verificação no seu próprio sistema.

**Boas práticas**

O recomendado é que você crie uma Factory de conexões ao banco, um Data access object para manipular o acesso e aquisição das informações ao banco e, por fim, uma que permita você validar se as informações são válidas ou não. Procure por pattern de Bancos de dados e JDBC

Comment: Muito obrigado, dei uma pesquisada na claúsula "where" que vc sugeriu e realmente ficou muito melhor.